# What does a Darlington pair do in a DC power supply circuit?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, power-electronics, linear-regulator, darlington

I really don't understand the role of the Darlington pair (T1) in this circuit. As it is a DC power supply circuit, I always thought that the pair is useful to have a high gain in audio and AOP circuits but in a power supply?  Does it have a regulation role?

[image: schematic of the circuit]

Comment: no different from a standard transistor, just higher current gain and Vbe is about 1.4V instead of 0.7V - otherwise it operates just the same way. The higher current gain likely improves the regulation a bit.

Comment: Your previous question about this circuit was a homework assignment. Is this still the case? What if it was not a darlington transistor, would it make any difference in understanding the circuit?

Comment: What does PWS mean?

Comment: @Andyaka Power supply :)

Comment: @danmcb that what I though but I can barely make the link between high current gain and regulation.

Comment: T1 controls the amount of current that flows, thus the resultant output voltage. The opamp does the regulation - it determines the difference between the required voltage and the output voltage and controls T1. The 741 doesn’t have a very strong output current so you need a transistor with high current gain to amplify the mA from the 741 to 2A for the output.